# Submitting one UpdatePanel clears the checkbox input in a different UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel

I have two check boxes in an update panel.  One is an ASP.NET CheckBox control, the other is just an HTML `<input>` element.  I have a button in a *different* update panel.

So here's the relevant portion of the page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" />HTML Input<br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="check2" Text="ASP CheckBox"></asp:CheckBox><br />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Submit" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I check both check boxes, then I click the button.  What I'm seeing is the check mark disappears from the one that's just HTML, but the check mark is still there for the CheckBox control.

Why?  I would have thought that *nothing* in the first update panel would change, because I'm doing a partial postback of the second update panel.

If I move the two checkboxes out of the update panel, then both keep their check marks (as I would have expected).

Comment: Mitchel Sellers answer explains it.  I will add that I shouldn't have been surprised that the CheckBox control behaved differently than the input element (even though they both render as input elements).  The page will start from its defaults each time through the page lifecycle, but the CheckBox will restore the posted value in its LoadPostData method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess here is that your update panels need to be configured so that ONLY the update panel that is actually used is updated.  When UpdatePanel2 is updated both panels are updating.  I believe that as long as you set the UpdateMode="Conditional" property on UpdatePanel1, you will get the desired effect.

You can see this MSDN Documentation on the [UpdateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) property.

Comment: This explains it, thank you.  I guess I was thinking that the behavior you get from UpdateMode="Conditional" was the default, but it's not.